# Onloading data(image in this case) from JSON it displays the images in browser but in that TAB keeps on spinning?

Tags: javascript, json

On running the code in browser the spinner doesn't stop spinning i.e it keeps on loading how can I stop after the data from JSON is loaded.Link to JSON data -> http://starlord.hackerearth.com/sureify/cokestudio

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var requestURL = 'http://starlord.hackerearth.com/sureify/cokestudio';

        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

        request.open('GET', requestURL);

        request.responseType = 'json';

        request.send();

        request.onload = function(){
            var myjsondata = request.response; //request.response contains all our JSON data
            showdata(myjsondata);

        } 

        function showdata(data){
            for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
            var str = "<IMG src='"+data[i].cover_image+"'/>";
            document.write(str);
            }
        }
    </script>
```

See the screenshot for better understanding:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Everything looks OK here.

Open your browser's developer tools and take a look at the "Network" tab, you'll probably find the cause there.

Comment: I have seen network in developer tools everything is working but why is that spinner not stopping.

Answer (score 0):

That's probably because the images are still loading.

Comment: @rockstone I cannot reproduce that. For me the images loaded in about ten seconds and it stopped.

Comment: did you tried on mozilla I am using mozilla in chrome spinner doesn't come it works fine in chrome.